# Mac OS X + Apache + Web Sharing

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, httpd

I'm running Mac OS X (Snow Leopard) and I'm trying to use Eclipse PDT and I'd like to use "Web Sharing" built-in feature that basically runs Apache. I'm doing code change in PDT and I want to use Safari and be able to hit my own server ( `localhost` ) and access those files without manually copying them over from one folder to another. How do I do that? I've tried

```
sudo vi /etc/apache2/users/alexus.conf
```

and then adding `/Alias` although that didn't help, in fact as soon as I hit myself at http://localhost/~alexus/workspace seems like it crashed my `apache`, or else I'm doing something wrong, this is what I get in my logs...

```
[Tue Sep 22 18:46:53 2009] [notice] caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Tue Sep 22 18:47:10 2009] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
```

Comment: seems you might want to look at that Session Cache error:

http://discussions.apple.com/thread.jspa?threadID=2091638

http://oscartheduck.wordpress.com/2007/04/25/session-cache-is-not-configured-hint-sslsessioncache-freebsd/

Comment: that is not even somewhat remotely related to my issue... not to mention I'm trying to hit localhost not some weird name, so there is no DNS issue in my case...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure why was it crashing, but by adding following line into

```
mbp:~ alexus$ grep ^Alias /etc/apache2/users/alexus.conf 
Alias /~alexus/workspace    /Users/alexus/workspace
mbp:~ alexus$
```

did the trick...